# Is extracting the first line from a file that is accessed via NFS thread safe?

Tags: nfs, concurrency

If I mount a directory via NFS on multiple servers each running a process that reads and deletes the first line of a specific file in that directory, can it somehow be guaranteed that no line is read twice or deleted without beeing extracted?

I could obviously create some sort of mutex that only allows one process to operate on the NFS-mounted file, but is there a build in way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> If I mount a directory via NFS on multiple servers each running a process that reads and deletes the first line of a specific file in that directory, can it somehow be guaranteed that no line is read twice or deleted without beeing extracted?

You can guarantee that the line won't be deleted without being extracted very easily:  simply don't do that.  Don't have your processing delete the line unless it's already "extracted" it, whatever that is.

Can you guarantee that a line will only be processed once?  Not really - there are all kinds of timing holes in NFS.  Data and metadata are cached on every client and even if all caching is disabled there are significant time delays in the network data transfers.  A process on one server may not "see" something happen until it's too late.

But you've seemingly missed an even bigger problem:  to delete the first line of a file requires rewriting the entirety of the rest of the file.  As it seems like you're trying to use this file as some sort of FIFO, I also assume you have other processes appending lines to the end of the file.  How well do you think that's going to work when you've got multiple clients rewriting the entire file after they each delete the first line?  Even *if* you can get the clients properly synchronized, you'd have to add any writing processes into your synchronization cluster.

And that's pretty much what you need to create - a software cluster all sharing a single file that needs to be fully locked to update its contents - whether to rewrite the entire file without its first line, or to append to the end of the file.

Can it be done reliably?  Sure, but not by using only NFS.

If you are thinking of using a file as a FIFO, you'd probably do better simply putting each line into a separate file, then using [`rename()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html) to move the file from a common directory to a client-specific directory on the same NFS-mounted file system.  Each client would have its own directory, and if the `rename()` worked it would know that it had successfully "claimed" that one file, and if it failed it would assume another client had "claimed" the file.

Hopefully, your NFS implementation is robust enough to handle conflicting `rename()` attempts properly on the NFS server where only one client works and gets a successful return from `rename()` and all other clients get a failure - without locking up the NFS server or crashing the kernel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was planning to use a NFS mount to distribute parameters for a batch processing job to worker processes in a local cloud system. But apparently I should reevaluate my plan.